# How to get values of specif tag from webpage in VB.net using WebRequest

Tags: vb.net

So basically i want receive data of webpage but only of specific class name elements or tag name values.

```
<div>
    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-187px;"><strong>1111</strong></div>
    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-150px;"><strong>2222</strong></div>
    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-114px;"><strong>3333</strong></div>
    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-77px;"><strong>4444</strong></div>
    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-42px;"><strong>5555</strong></div>
</div>
```

From above i want all the values of tag name strong or elements of abc class.
So my output should be something like this

> 1111
>   2222
>   3333
>   4444
>   5555

I have created following

```
Dim inStream As StreamReader
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("url here")
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
inStream = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim str As String = inStream.ReadToEnd()
Textbox1.Text = str
```

but as you can see it's fetch whole page but i just want specif tag or class name elements.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What you want is parsing HTML and for this you have either to rely on an external library or on the WebBrowser class... Or to create a custom parsing algorithm although this does not seem too practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML.

**Example:** *(should be enough to get you started)*

```
Dim html = <html>
                <div>
                    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-187px;"><strong>1111</strong></div>
                    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-150px;"><strong>2222</strong></div>
                    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-114px;"><strong>3333</strong></div>
                    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-77px;"><strong>4444</strong></div>
                    <div class="abc" style="margin-top:-42px;"><strong>5555</strong></div>
                </div>
            </html>
            
Dim htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html.ToString())

For Each node In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='abc']//strong")
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.ToString())
Next
```

**Result**:

> 1111
> 2222
> 3333
> 4444
> 5555

Comment: Thank you for showing me path done what i wanted.
Thank you so much