# How can I get the first div on a webpage?

Tags: html, vb.net, browser, html-agility-pack

Does anyone know how to get the first div's child's child's link?

This is how the page looks:

```
    <div id="id1" class="class-1 class-2 class-3 class-4 class-5 class-6 class-7">
                        <div class="class 8 class 9">
                            <h3><a href="http://foo.com/1">foo.com/1</a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

  <div id="id2" class="class-1 class-2 class-3 class-4 class-5 class-6 class-7">
                        <div class="class 8 class 9">
                            <h3><a href="http://foo.com/2">foo.com/2</a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

  <div id="id3" class="class-1 class-2 class-3 class-4 class-5 class-6 class-7">
                        <div class="class 8 class 9">
                            <h3><a href="http://foo.com/3">foo.com/3</a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I'd like to get the first div, but the id changes every time it navigates.
Therefore, I need a code that gets the first div on the page, and then gets the child's link. Then, the WebBrowser can go to that link.

This is what I have tried:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://foo.com/home")
WebBrowser1.
```

Comment: You could get the text of the page into a string and then use HtmlAgilityPack to locate the link.

Comment: How? Can you help me? Guide me?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118491/how-to-get-values-of-specif-tag-from-webpage-in-vb-net-using-webrequest

Comment: That example doesn't help me because I need the first div, and the classes and ids change each time, plus I only need the first one...

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and stop being so lazy. This is a Q&A site, not a code writing service.

Comment: @Beginner HtmlAgilityPack isn't required here, as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: @cybermonkey - I think most here would agree using RegularExpressions to parse HTML is...ah...not an optimal solution.

Comment: @SteveWellens Multiple bits of HTML perhaps, but the as the OP only requires the first match regex is completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

The below code retrieves the link inside the first `<h3><a href="http://foo.com/1">foo.com/1</a></h3>`:

```
    Dim wc As New WebClient
    Dim html As String = wc.DownloadString([.URL link.])
    Dim txt As String = html.ToString()

    Dim re1 As String = ".*?" 'Non-greedy match on filler
    Dim re2 As String = "(http)"  'Word 1
    Dim re3 As String = "(:)" 'Any Single Character 1
    Dim re4 As String = "(\/)"    'Any Single Character 2
    Dim re5 As String = "((?:\/[\w\.\-]+)+)"  'Unix Path 1

    Dim r As Regex = New Regex(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim m As Match = r.Match(txt)
    If (m.Success) Then
        Dim s1 = m.Groups(1)
        Dim s2 = m.Groups(2)
        Dim s3 = m.Groups(3)
        Dim s4 = m.Groups(4)
        Dim url As String = m.Groups(1).ToString() + m.Groups(2).ToString() + m.Groups(3).ToString() + m.Groups(4).ToString()
        [.do whatever with the URL here.]
    End If
```

Modified code from [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/), an online Regular Expression tool, [this is the source.](http://txt2re.com/index-vb.php3?s=%3Ch3%3E%3Ca%20href=%22http://foo.com/1%22%3Efoo.com/1%3C/a%3E%3C/h3%3E&-13&5&-75&-76&-85&-77&4)

Note that you need to access the `Net` and `RegularExpressions` namespaces, so you'll also need:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Net
```

Comment: I don't understand what happens here... Do you mind explaining? Thanks.

Comment: @Beginner Regex (aka Regular Expression) is a form of string matching which also allows to easily retrieve the desired objects from a string input if you know roughly what that input is going to look like. The code I provided matches the appropriate string your webpage has (`<h3><a href="http://foo.com/1">foo.com/1</a></h3>`) and finds the link. It only captures the first occurrence but however you could easily make it retrieve *every* match if you really wanted to.

Comment: That's just what I need! Thanks!

Comment: @Beginner Excellent, glad I solved your problem. Please mark my answer as 'accepted' by clicking the tick below the voting buttons.